# Bukkit plugin compilation problems

Tags: java, compiler-errors, minecraft, bukkit

I'm coding a bukkit plugin. It's player counter per world and scoreboard.  Really simple, but I have some problems with the code.

Take a look at it.
http://pastebin.com/PCEj0Vkj

I don't see the error, but compilator says that there are errors in:

http://prntscr.com/4vaegq

and on last line on "`}`"

I would love to show you error log and more screenshots, but I need 10+ reps.

Comment: "I would love to show you error log and more screenshots, but I need 10+ reps." Don't put the image in your question, put the actual text. It'll be easier to see, and it'll also make it much easier for other people to stumble onto your question later.

Comment: Thanks, I will have that in mind when i post next time.

Comment: @Darko - please edit your question to include a minimal complete verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your code, starting at line 25 and ending at line 45 needs to go in either an initialisation block or inside a method body.

Comment: Thank you, now it works, but I still wanna know why doesn't it work other way? 
Thanks again.

Comment: That's just the syntax of java - a class body can only be used to declare fields, constructors, methods, and initialisation blocks.